# MongoDB: Aggregation, group by several fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents, of that structure

```
{
  type: 'a',
  date: '2014-01-04'
},
{
  type: 'b',
  date: '2014-01-04'
},
{
  type: 'b',
  date: '2014-01-04
},
{
  type: 'c',
  date: '2014-01-03'
},
{
  type: 'a',
  date: '2014-01-03'
}
```

I want to aggregate that data by date and type (group by date and count by type):

```
{
  date: '2014-01-04': {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2
  },

  date: '2014-01'03': {
    'a': 1,
    'c': 1
  }
}
```

I have aggregate function, like this

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { user: user },
    },
    {
        $group: { _id: {date: '$date'}, count: {$sum: 1}, services: {$push: '$type'}}
    }
], function (err, results) {
```

But doing that I still need to `reduce` results by services.

Can this be done with one aggregation query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assuming you have fixed number of types, you can solve it as follows :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{$group : {_id : "$date", 
           a:{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:['$type','a']},1,0]}},
           b:{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:['$type','b']},1,0]}},
           c:{$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:['$type','c']},1,0]}}
}},
{$project : {_id : 0, date : "$_id", a: "$a", b : "$b", c : "$c"}}
)
```

Comment: that seems to me as very close to answer of @Derick. assume that his answer is editited..

Comment: You can check the time of the answer. I have answered before than Derick.

Answer (score 3):

You can of course group by more than one field:

```
{ $group: { _id: { date: '$date', services: '$services' } }
```

But that is not what you want it seems. You can not every easily convert data to keys, unless you can do that all by hand. The following query would be an option:

```
db.test.aggregate( [
    { $group: {
        '_id' : { date: '$date' },
        a: { $sum: { 
            $cond: [ { $eq: [ '$type', 'a' ] }, 1, 0 ]  
        } },
        b: { $sum: { 
            $cond: [ { $eq: [ '$type', 'b' ] }, 1, 0 ]
        } },
        c: { $sum: { 
            $cond: [ { $eq: [ '$type', 'c' ] }, 1, 0 ] 
        } },
    } },
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        date: '$_id.date',
        a: '$a',
        b: '$b',
        c: '$c',
    } }
] );
```

You will need to manually add a line for each new type.

Comment: This is not correct. "$_id.a", "$_id.b" and "$_id.c" will not return any result. In the group part _id object does not contain a,b,c fields.

Comment: Yeap, I have fixed amount of types - so your query looks interesting. I didn't know $project could go after $group. will try it asap.